# Web Deploy (MSDeploy) API "postSync:runCommand"

Tags: msdeploy, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a website via the Web Deploy API (Microsoft.Web.Deployment).

Using the msdelpoy.exe, I could do as many -postSync:runcommand's (or preSync) as I like, but I can't see how to do that via the API.

Here is my deployment script in powershell, but you can see the .net classes being used.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Deployment")
function CallMSDeploy([string]$destinationServer, [string]$destinationIISSiteName, $sourceDirectory)
{
    $destBaseOptions   = new-object Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentBaseOptions
    $destBaseOptions.UserName = $deployUserName
    $destBaseOptions.Password = $deployPassword
    $destBaseOptions.ComputerName = $destinationServer

    $syncOptions       = new-object Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncOptions

    $deploymentObject = [Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager]::CreateObject("contentPath", $sourceDirectory)
    $deploymentObject.SyncTo("contentPath",$destinationIISSiteName,$destBaseOptions,$syncOptions);
}
```

I know that I can new up a Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObjectProvider using the "runCommand" provider and specifiy a path, but how do I add it to the preSync of the above deployment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preSync` / `postSync` is a feature of the msdeploy command line, not the `Microsoft.Web.Deployment` API itself. Both are basically just a call to `CreateObject().SyncTo(destOptions)`, where `destOptions` are copied from the main sync.

You should have no troubles reproducing it in PS.